# Attribute to Prevent Slash (/) and Backslash (\)?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have a text field property where I do not want users to be able to enter forward or back slashes.  Is there a data attribute for this or do I need to use the `RegularExpression` attribute?

This seems like it would be pretty common, but I am not having any luck finding the answer. I'm not familiar with Regular Expressions, so I'm researching them now.

Comment: @AdamMaras, Yes! Thanks. The values are used in a filepath type reference in a 3rd party component, so I need the data to not contain the slashes.

Comment: `String.Replace` perhaps?

Comment: What about other characters that also don't work for file paths, such as : ? Your question seems to ask to allow those.

Comment: @Magnus, I thought about that, but would prefer the user get the feedback.

Comment: @hvd, it's not exactly a filepath reference so I don't think those would cause an issue, but I would not have a problem restricting those values as well.

Comment: If other characters don't cause issues, then don't block them. I was only asking because I figured they might not work right for you either. :)

Comment: @hvd, thanks. Was just curious if there was another approach that validated on filepath values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`RegularExpressionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) for this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\\/]*$")]
```

---

To break the regex down:

```
^ ... $
```

The `^` and `$` respectively denote the beginning and the end of the field. This wrapper forces the *entire* string to match the regex to validate.

```
[^ ... ]*
```

This is a *negated character class* that can occur zero or more times. To match, the string must not contain any of the characters inside this container.

```
\\
/
```

The first character, the backslash, must be escaped. The forward slash must not.

Once you put it all together, you have a regex that states that nowhere in the string can you have a backslash or a forward slash.

---

Here, try it out on [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OhJJWVe9F4CR2igN).

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! Works great and I'll definitely bookmark debuggex!